# Is there a JGit method equivalent to git rev-parse --short?

Tags: jgit

Does JGit include an implementation of `git rev-parse --short`? I could not find one in perusing the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to `git rev-parse` in JGit.

However, JGit provides API that may help to achieve what rev-parse does.

- `ObjectId::isId()` to determine if the given string represents a SHA-1
- `ObjectId::fromString()` to create an `ObjectId` from a string

To shorten a given object id, use `ObjectId::abbreviate()`

The following example abbreviates the given SHA-1:

```java
ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.fromString( "fb808b5b01cdfaedda0bd1d304c7115ce959b286" );
AbbreviatedObjectId abbreviatedId = objectId.abbreviate( 7 );  // returns fb808b5
```

Note that the methods outlined above operate independent of a repository and thus cannot detect ambiguous object ids or verify if a given id exists in a repository or if it has the expected type (things that `git rev-parse --verify` would do).

To verify an id with a repository `Repository::resolve` can be used. The method accepts expressions like `fb808b5^{commit}` and returns an `ObjectId`, or `null` if the string can't be resolved. an `AmbiguousObjectException` is thrown if the repository contains more than one match. See the JavaDoc for a list of supported expressions: http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.html#resolve(java.lang.String)

Be aware, that an `IncorrectObjectTypeException` is thrown if an object type is specified, but the revision that was found does not match the given type.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use it on a given `Git git`? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the post. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Just to make a straightforward example for what @Rüdiger Herrmann mentioned above

```
// git rev-parse HEAD
git.getRepository().exactRef("refs/heads/master").getObjectId().name()

// git rev-parse --short HEAD
git.getRepository().exactRef("refs/heads/master").getObjectId().abbreviate(7).name()
```